# Uploading data into hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

---

### |  id(String)|  name(String)| value(jsonb)|

### |    A1       |   JOHN       | {"ID":"phils"}|

this is my table structure..
which is the best way to data upload into hazelcast.. so that i can do query these fields using sqlPredicate

Comment: load data into hazelcast map,and name is the key in map.